# Get Yii DB Cache id of saved record in cache table

Tags: yii

I have a query like this:

```
$record=books::model()->cache(10000)->find('id=:id',array(":id"=>$id));
```

Yii uses CDbCache to save the result in the cache table

```
id     expire      value 
--     ------      ------
```

My question is:

> How to get the id of the cache record -this id is generated by yii -  in
>   yii cache table?

Answer (score 1):

There's no public method to get the cache ID, as it incorporates a lot of variables, you could if you really wanted to but it's really dark down in the depths of Yii.

Answer based on comments:

You could always set a last cached time on your record, which you can then use to calculate the time remaining. But this won't persist over page spans, because your caching you result and it won't get read again. So your options are:

- Do the caching manually, and store the time against the object to be used for calculation
- Or store the time for each ID pulled in the session, and use that to calculate it.

Comment: thank u but i think this is not related to my question. how do you fetch id of saved record in cache table in your query. this's my question.?

Comment: I assumed you meant find the ID so you could delete the record, which is what this will do. Why do you need the ID? There is logic in how Yii generates these IDs but it's very dangerous to rely on this data being correct or even existing.

Comment: i want to know when cache expire and  use remaining time to expire.

Comment: Ah so you want a count of the time left on this records cache. I'll give it a little thought on how best to do this. But in the meantime, why? It doesn't give you any useful information about the data, except how out of date it **might** be.

Comment: yeah. i need only time . i have implemented what i need in another way. but i think this is nice and easier option if i could get id  with yii function -

Comment: Updated answer, but seriously, why do you need this information?

Comment: it's complicated but i want to say to users "results calculated 2 hours ago and results updated after 3 hours  in best selling books today part". i cached results and get id of cache and next time i calculate time()-expire time

Comment: OK, well if it's a complicated query that makes it even less of a good idea to try and manually get the ID. Maybe you could use an analysis table and get rid of the caching. Do all your complex calculation and put the results into a table, along with when it was calculated. Every page request pulls from here, and if it's expired regenerates it. You'd then have access to the time left.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer this question. By the way the Yii code is written, you can't get the ID/Key for the Cache which the YII generates internally.
If you look at the sourcecode

> https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/db/CDbCommand.php
>   Method **queryInternal**

You'll realize that the **cacheKey** generation is the complex thing. Moreover this cacheKey will further be Hashed by MD5

> Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache#generateUniqueKey-detail

If you are using 'cache' as part of QueryBuilder, then we are giving the power to Yii to manage this cache by providing the Expire Duration and Dependency Query.

If you want to be in command/control of the Expire Duration and want to have the ID, then only way is to manually set the CacheID as suggested by the user 
[Paystey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/737033/paystey) as belowt:

```
$dbResult = Yii::app()->cache->get('YOUR-KNOWN-KEY');
if($dbResult === false){
    $dbResult = YOUR-QUERY;
    Yii::app()->cache->set('YOUR-KNOWN-KEY, $dbResult);
}
```